# If the JWT token for auth is saved in the HTTP-Only cookie, how do you read it from the cookie so that I can include it in request header?

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, jwt

I am building a Node web app using JWT for user auth.

My server sends JWT in **HTTP-Only** cookie via 'Set-Cookie' when user submits correct id and password, but I am stuck on how to access that JWT stored within the cookie so that I can include it in the Authorization header when making authorized API requests.

How can I access the HTTP-Only cookie from client-side to include it when sending API request to server?

Or, would it be safe to just not use the cookie at all by having the server send the JWT in response body?  So that I use the JWT by putting it in a client-side variable?  That way, I believe the variable is only alive until the user closes the browser.

I have looked for many resources, but was not able to find clear answer to this issue that I am stuck with.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am not using any client-side framework such as React or Vue.  Just plain Javascript on client side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While there are numerous ways to solve this problem, I will suggest the method where the client sends the JWT twice on each request: in an HttpOnly cookie, and also an an `Authentication:` header.

---

Let's examine what security issue each is solving:

## HttpOnly Cookie

From [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies):

> To help mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks, HttpOnly cookies are inaccessible to JavaScript's Document.cookie API; they are only sent to the server.

This is to mitigate cross-site scripting risk; imagine your website has an XSS vuln -- for example I can put `<script>some_code{..}</script>` into a comment, and any user who views my comment will have my code running in their browser. Yes, the attacker's code is running inside the victim's logged-in browser, but because of the `HttpOnly` flag, it can't extract the session cookie and send it to the attacker.

## Authentication header

The problem with cookie authentication is that the browser will automatically attach them to any request to the domain that the cookie belongs to, this allows [cross-site request forgery](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) attacks. To prevent this, the usual method is to send the session token (in your case a JWT) to the client in a method other than a cookie, ie in a different header, or maybe in a hidden HTML field.

If the client is able to echo the JWT token back to you on their next request, that means they were able to read the previous response, and are not an attacker doing a blind injection CSRF attack.

---

## Overall Suggestion

Combine the two!

The two methods serve different purposes: HttpOnly cookies protect against XSS attacks while Authentication headers protect against CSRF attacks.

There are many ways to combine them, but they all boil down to putting the JWT in some sort of authentication header, and putting a sessionID in the cookie, and having the server check that these belong to the same session. Important: remember that an attacker who achieves XSS on your site will be able to read the JWT, so for the cookie to be doing its job, the cookie should be a separate value that is not contained in the JWT. (ie if the attacker can figure out the right cookie value by looking at the JWT, then the cookie is not providing any security).

Comment: Samesite cookie attribute can be used to prevent CSRF attacks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite